# Covert 3 levels nested json to Alamofire parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have a really complex json need to send my API with Alamofire like this

```js
{
  "usernme": "test",
  "roastData": {
    "temps": [
    {"timing": 1, "state":1, "temp": 100},
    {"timing": 2, "state":1, "temp": 101},
    ]
  }
}
```

for sending it, need to convert this json to type as[String: AnyObject].

it should become

```
["usernme": "test",
 "roastData": [
    "temps": [
      ["timing": 1, "state":1, "temp": 100],
      ["timing": 2, "state":1, "temp": 101],
    ]
    "date": "someDateHere"
  ]
]
```

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have JSON String the you can convert it into Dictionary by following code:

```
// jsonString contains your JSON.
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
do {
    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
    // Use dictionary here
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Some of your answer is right, but object inside the first level will still look like JSON type, not [String:Any]. It won't be read at server side

Comment: What do you mean by JSON type? it is in form of [String: Any] and will work perfectly with Alamofire.

Comment: I mean the result of your function can't totally convert object inside another object. roastData wont be get correctly by my server API

Comment: You should add the code for sending the request with Alamofire.